# Windows Backup - Backups Deleted but Disk is not Free

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I have a windows 2008 r2 server box, where i have configured weekly backups using the windows backup software, the backup disk is a iscsi shared nas disk, we had 12 backups and the disk was full, so we deleted 8 old backups.

but the backup isnt working any more, windows says no free disk.

i deleted the backup using Disk Shadow

I issue command delete shadows id {xyz} and deleted old backups one by one.

i did not issue a reset command

do i need to issue a reset command?

Comment: You might want to check the filesystem on that LUN with chkdsk. Filling a filesystem can have adverse effects on the structure if errors occured during that time. Just a maybe.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK your backup catalog stats will be automatically updated during the next backup job.

Try to create a new small backup job pointing to the same target, then run it and see if helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, but I found the root cause, it was a problem with the SQLServerWriter, I restarted the service and managed to start Backups.

Thanks once again